# How do I check validate of actors who have been in a movie with both actor X and actor Z (but not necessarily at the same time)

Tags: javascript, object, curl, fetch-api

I have an JavaScript coding assessment and need your opinions,
Provides a list of movies and the actors that starred in them.
so I have to use these end points to get the data, and I already did,but stuck on the validation POST request and couldn't know what should be the body objects exactly.

```
curl --request GET \
--url https://switch-yam-equator.azurewebsites.net/api/movies \
--header 'x-chmura-cors: <access_token>'

[
{ "movieId": 365478,
"title": "Man with the Screaming Brain",
"actors": [331341, 132257, 126364, 1646]

}, ...
]
```

Actors
Provides a list of actors and their IDs.

```
curl --request GET \
--url https://switch-yam-equator.azurewebsites.net/api/actors \
--header 'x-chmura-cors: <access_token>'

[
{ "actorId": 168,
"title": "Samuel L. Jackson"
}, ...
]
```

Validation
Accepts results in JSON format and returns an HTTP 200 response if the data are correct.

```
curl --request POST \
--url https://switch-yam-equator.azurewebsites.net/api/validation \
--header 'x-chmura-cors: <access_token>' \
--data '<results>'

[
{
"Name": "Alan Smithee",
"KRMovies": [
"The Matrix",
"The Matrix Revolutions"
]

"NCMovies": [
```

So I got the matching actors and return their IDs and their names,but when attached the name and the title to the body it shows this
error:

> " error": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

So please any thoughts would be perfect for someone on my situation.

Comment: Why is this tagged `javascript`? There's no JS code here. This is all shell code.

Comment: What do you mean by "attached the name and the title to the body"? Body of what?

Comment: Apologize for my language, but technically when I did the POST request using fetch 
header:{
.....},
body:JSON.Stringfiy([{"actorId":123,"name":"..."},{..}]
so my question is for checking the validate of actors what should be the body object that should handeling the data and return the result as shown above

Comment: correct its a shell code and I have attached the curl request per the documents of this assessment ,but I'm using fetch request instead.to get and post the data

Comment: Please post the actual code that's getting that error.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation of the API you're calling?